# Memoir: book + articles

Tags: memoir

I have a book (memoir class) and few articles (memoir[article] class).

I want to put articles in the end of the book, so that they would appear as they were processed originally).

I would like to have a single `.tex` document (since I have cross-references between book and articles, and between articles).

I understand, that some editing will be required.

```
%%%% Minimal example of standalone article

\documentclass[12pt,oneside,openany, article]{memoir}

\pagestyle{headings}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\nouppercaseheads

\title{Some creative thinking about miscellaneous stupid things}

\author{Victor Ivrii}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\chapter{Introduction}

\blindtext[5]

\bibliographystyle{amsplain}

\begin{thebibliography}{9}

\bibitem[AM]{crap}

John Doe \emph{Some crap}

\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}

%%%Embedding it into a book

\documentclass[12pt,oneside,openany]{memoir}

\pagestyle{headings}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\nouppercaseheads



\begin{document}

\title{My Book}

\author{Victor}

\chapter{Some crap}

\blindtext



\renewcommand{\thesection}{\arabic{section}}

\title{Some creative thinking about miscellaneous stupid things}

\author{Victor}

\maketitle

\section{Introduction}

\blindtext[5]

\bibliographystyle{amsplain}

\begin{thebibliography}{9}

\bibitem[AM]{crap}

John Doe \emph{Some crap}

\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}

%%%%%%%%%%%
```

We see that

1. Running heads are displaying in the article  CHAPTER (actually previous chapter of the book) while it should be SECTION inside the article.
2. Bibliography in the embedded article starts from the new page (unlike in the article) and the word "Bibliography" is printed in larger fonts.

PS Sure, book has its own bibliography which should look like bibliography in the book.

---

Added: March 04, 2018:

```
 \renewcommand{\bibsection}{\section*{\bibname}\prebibhook}
```

The result was that running header over Bibliography was the one from the previous section. I changed it to

```
\renewcommand{\bibsection}{\section{\bibname}\prebibhook}
```

which fixed the running header but added unwanted "section" number to Bibliography, which I fixed by preceding it by

```
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{0}
```

Comment: Welcome, your question is a bit too broad. What kind of answer are you expecting? *Should just work*? Where is the problem right now?

Comment: Crosspost on texhax.

Comment: This should not have that hard to fix. But please provide a minimal example so we have something to work with.

Comment: Please explain what you mean by "do a similar thing with the TOC"? The bibliography and the TOC are different constructions, and this does not share structure.

Comment: Please ask a new question instead of completely change the existing question.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this might be a starting point.

```
\documentclass[12pt,oneside,openany]{memoir}
\pagestyle{headings}

\usepackage{kantlipsum}

\nouppercaseheads
% need reactivation for \nouppercaseheads to have an effect
\pagestyle{headings}

\setsecnumdepth{subsubsection}
\maxsecnumdepth{subsubsection}

% adjusted from memoir sources (look for \ifartopt)
\newcommand\InternalArticleOption{
  % assumes oneside, use "both" instead of "right" in twosided case
  \addtopsmarks{headings}{}{%
    \createmark{section}{right}{shownumber}{}{. \ }
    \createmark{subsection}{right}{shownumber}{}{. \ }
    \createmark{subsubsection}{right}{shownumber}{}{. \ }
  }
  % reactivation
  \pagestyle{headings}
  % adjust \maketitle
  \renewcommand{\maketitlehookb}{%
    \vskip -1.5\topsep\vskip -1.5\partopsep}
  \renewcommand{\maketitlehookc}{%
    \vskip -1.5\topsep\vskip -1.5\partopsep}
  % adjust bibliography (it is using \chapter* by deafault, under
  % articl option, \chapter* behaves like \section*, we just foce it
  % to use \section*)
  \renewcommand{\bibsection}{\section*{\bibname}\prebibhook}
  % remove chapter from section number
  \renewcommand{\thesection}{\arabic{section}}
}


\begin{document}

\title{My Book}

\author{Victor}

\chapter{Some crap}

\kant



\InternalArticleOption



\title{Some creative thinking about miscellaneous stupid things}

\author{Victor}

\maketitle

\section{Introduction}

\kant[5]

\subsection{Test}

\kant[7]


\bibliographystyle{amsplain}

\begin{thebibliography}{9}

\bibitem[AM]{crap}

John Doe \emph{Some crap}

\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
```

---

Addition: There is a bug in `memoir` in its handling of `\maketitle`, it does not reset the thanks data, which may result in accumulative thanks build up. Also, the counter value used by `\thanks` continues from where it left of. Easy fix:

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\maketitlehooka{
  \setcounter{footnote}{0}
  \global\let\@thanks\@empty
}
\makeatother
```

in the preamble. `memoir` probably never had repeated use of `\maketitle` in mind.

Normally when I make docs that lists articles (often seen in PhD theses), I tend to write my own interface that does not use `\maketitle`. Then the student can also include information like where this was published, abstract etc. From that we then build a suitable title page for the article (and add whatever we like to the general ToC).

---

EDIT: memoir not resitting thanks is not really a bug, it is even mentioned in the manual, with the suggestion of using

```
\emptythanks
\maketitle
```

if you need to use `\maketitle` many times, since `\emptythanks` is just `\global\let\@thanks\@empty`, the suggestion from above reduces to

```
\renewcommand\maketitlehooka{
  \emptythanks
}
```

As multi using `\maketitle` is not that frequent, I'll  just leave it at that, since `\emptythanks` is already mentioned in the manual (aka I do not see this a a bug, as I first wrote and as such will not fix it at present).

Comment: One more problem: accumulation of thanks: 

%%% Example\documentclass[12pt]{memoir}

\begin{document}

\title{About rhinos}

\thanks{To Rhinos}

\maketitle

Rhinos are cool!

\title{About raccoons}

\thanks{To Raccoonss}

\maketitle

Raccoons are cool!

\end{document}

Comment: @Victor, please don't use comments for this, make it an addition to your question instead

Comment: @Victor suggestion added, also added this to my todo list for `memoir`